# VHDL - How to Define Port Map of a component with a package in its entity?

Tags: vhdl

I am trying to use packages to shift block of data within different components via top level entity.

I have defined a package with array as

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;

package my_array_pkg is
 type my_array is array ( 0 to 9) of std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
end my_array_pkg;
```

---

Then in top level entity I have declared my components as,

```
COMPONENT Array_Count is
Port ( C_1Hz    : in std_logic;
        reset : in std_logic;
        digit  : out my_array
        );
end COMPONENT;
```

Now can someone help me about how to declare this "digit  : out my_array" in the port map.

---

```
C2 : Array_Count
    PORT MAP ( CLK1HZ, RESET, ????);
```

---

The array package needed to be updated in other component.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to "use" the package before the entity declaration :

```
use work.my_array_pkg.all;
```

or

```
library my_library; 
use my_library.my_array_pkg.all;
```

to make the package contents visible.

Then you need to declare a signal of that type before you instantiate the component, for example:

```
signal my_digit : my_array;
```

and now connect the port to that signal

```
C2 : Array_Count
    PORT MAP ( 
        C_1Hz => CLK1HZ, 
        reset => RESET, 
        digit => my_digit);
```